# C++ class static member function calling error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, static-methods, static-functions

I write a project with visual studio. In the project I build a class called CSimApplianceDlg which has two members:

`static UINT RecvDataFrame(LPVOID pParam)` and `CSerialPort m_Port`

```
class CSimApplianceDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
CSimApplianceDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL); // standard constructor

// Implementation
protected:
HICON m_hIcon;

// Added for Serial Port operation
static UINT RecvDataFrame(LPVOID pParam); // Process received data
......
private:
......
unsigned char m_SendData[MAX_LEN]; // Data to be sent
int len;                           // the length of data to be sent
public:
CSerialPort m_Port;     // CSerialPort Object
......
```

`CSerialPort` has a public member function `WriteToPort` to send data through serial port.

```
public:
void      WriteToPort(char* string);
void      WriteToPort(char* string,int n);
void      WriteToPort(LPCTSTR string);
void      WriteToPort(LPCTSTR string,int n);
```

I called

`m_Port.WriteToPort(m_SendData,len);`

in UINT CSimApplianceDlg::RecvDataFrame(LPVOID pParam). However, while building the project, just at the line of the calling, I got

> 1>e:\mysourcecode\smarthome\simappliance\simappliance\simappliancedlg.cpp(557) 
>       : error C2228: left of '.WriteToPort' must have class/struct/union
>    1>e:\mysourcecode\smarthome\simappliance\simappliance\simappliancedlg.cpp(557) : error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'CSimApplianceDlg::m_SendData'
>    1>e:\mysourcecode\smarthome\simappliance\simappliance\simappliancedlg.cpp(557) : error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'CSimApplianceDlg::len'

How can I deal with these errors? And which `WriteToPort` is called, because I 
am not familiar with `LPCTSTR`.

Comment: You forgot to show the code where those errors occur.

Comment: You have probably failed to create an *instance* of the `CSerialPort` class. As Michael has said, we can't tell for sure unless we can see the actual code. Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: errors applears in calling "m_Port.WriteToPort(m_SendData,len);"

Answer (score 0):

The function static UINT RecvDataFrame(LPVOID pParam) is static. It means you can call it without an instantiation of the object CSimApplianceDlg. In other words you can call CSimApplianceDlg::RecvDataFrame() from anywhere which is often the case for call back function.
This means that within that function, you cannot access the member variables (m_Port).
As pointed earlier, we do not have enough information to help but it's likely that the pParam passed has a pointer to the object... alternatively, if it's the only window in your app, you can try AfxGetMainWnd().
LPCTSTR is simply defined as const TCHAR *, where TCHAR is a char or a wchar_t
if your are in ANSI or Unicode. Good luck!